# How to print 2d-array with comma and new line

Tags: c

```
int **arr;  //For example: 4 by 3 array
```

How can I print 2d-array with comma and new line like below?

```
01, 02, 03, 04  // At last, new line without comma
05, 06, 07, 08 
09, 10, 11, 12
```

I need the fastest method to print like it.

Comment: The fastest is `puts("01, 02, 03, 04\n05, 06, 07, 08\n09, 10, 11, 12");`.  But how about showing what you have done and we can work on a more general purpose and fast solution?

Comment: Likely the _fastest_ method would compose the entire buffer and then _put_ it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution for any `m x n` matrix defined as a double pointer to type is:

```
/* print a (m x n) matrix */
void mtrx_prn (size_t m, size_t n, float **matrix)
{
    register size_t i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        char *pad = "[ ";
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf ("%s%6.3f", pad, matrix [i][j]);
            pad = ", ";
        }
        printf ("%s", " ]\n");
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/mtrx_dyn_example

[  1.900,  2.800,  3.700,  4.600 ]
[  2.800,  3.700,  4.600,  5.500 ]
[  3.700,  4.600,  5.500,  6.400 ]
```

Just adjust the data type (e.g. `int`, `double`, etc...) as needed.

Comment: Oh, that is missing `:p` I had a comment line above the change in `pad` and when I deleted it, I caught the next line too...

Comment: Alternative to `pad`, change `format` _might_ be speedier for `printf()` to decompose.

Comment: Yes, but you would still have to provide the first element alone without preceding comma, and let printf decompose `matrix[i][1]` on.

Comment: Example: `format = "[ %6.3f"; for (...) {  printf (format, matrix [i][j]); format = ", %6.3f"; } puts(" ]");`

Comment: Ahh..., that is completely different than I was envisioning. Thank you for that pearl. I'll go give it a test.

Comment: @chux looking, I think the speed difference would primarily come from the substitution of `puts` for the final `printf`, but even then, that is something the compiler will likely have substituted. Do you see it any differently?

Comment: `(f)printf()` is a black hole of CPU cycles.  For _speed_, forming the entire string to print and 1 call to `fputs()` (or `fwrite()`) likely wins the derby.  But I doubt that all those shenanigans are worth it (increased code complexity) as it is more likely just a local optimizations that does not reduce the O(n), just its co-efficient.  IMO, go for code clarity/maintenance and reasonable performance - not "fastest".

Answer (score 0):

You can use below logic to achieve that. Use conditional `printf` to skip comma for last term. And next time post what you have tried :)

```
for(int row=0;row<MaxRow;row++)
{
    for(int col=0;col<MaxCol;col++)
    {
        if(col == MaxcCol-1)
            printf(" %d",array[row][col]);
        else
            printf(" %d,",array[row][col]);//comma after %d
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Maybe put `printf(" %d",array[row][col]);` after the inner `for` loop.

Comment: yes but it gives impression that entity is outside of array if write outside of for loop - or just a style you can say.

Answer (score 0):

```
int row = 3, col=4;
char outbuff[(11+2)*row*col];
register char *p=outbuff;
for(int r = 0; r < row; ++r){
    for(int c = 0; c < col; ++c){
        if(c){
            *p++ =  ',';
            *p++ =  ' ';
        }
        p += sprintf(p, "%02d", arr[r][c]);
    }
    *p++ = '\n';
}
*p = 0;
fputs(outbuff, stdout);
```